# onStartJob is not getting called, except onCreate() in JobService Class

Tags: android-jobscheduler

onStartJob is not getting called at all, but onCreate of JobService Geting called, can someone suggest me, what's the reason.

the code prototype is here->

```
public class SyncToDB extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = "SyncService";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {

            Log.i(TAG, "on start job: " + params.getJobId());
            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
            return true;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hi there, you haven't quoted any code that would actually schedule the job - have you written any? It would normally involve `Job.Builder`

Comment: Please post code from where you are scheduling the job